# google analytics a/b testing with 2 site instances.

Tags: azure, google-analytics, multivariate-testing

I am getting ready to release a new web site in the coming weeks, and would like the ability to run multivariate or a/b tests between two version of the site.

The site is hosted on azure, and I am using the Service Gateway to split traffic between the instances of the site, both of which are deployed from Visual Studio Online. One from the main branch and the other from an "experimental" branch.

Can I configure Google analytics to assist me in tracking the success of my tests. From what I have read Google analytics seems to focus on multiple versions of a page within the same site for running its experiments.

I have though of perhaps using 2 separate tracking codes, but my customers are not overly technically savvy, so I would like to keep things as simple as possible. I have also considered collecting my own metrics inside the application, but I would prefer to use an existing tool as I don't really have the time to implement something like that.

can this be done? are there better options? is there a good nugget package that might fulfil my needs? any advice welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest setting a [custom dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets) that tells you which version of the site the user is on. Then in the reports you can segment and compare the data.

Comment: that looks like a solution. Thank you very much.